# How do I prefix Command stdout with [stdout] and [sterr]?

Tags: rust

Using the [Command struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html), how can I add a prefix to the stdout and stderr buffers?

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
[stdout] things are good.
[sterr] fatal: repository does not exist.
```

This would also be nice to apply to the program's main stdout so anything the program prints is prefixed like that.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
let output = Command::new("git").arg("clone").output().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
    panic!("Failed to run git clone: {}", e)
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe you can do what you truly want to do right now. Ideally, you'd be able to provide an implementor of `Write` to the `Process::stdout`  method. Unfortunately, the [set of choices for `Stdio`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.piped) is sparse. Perhaps you can campaign to have this be a feature request for Rust 1.1, or create a crate to start fleshing out some of the details (like cross-platform compatibility)

If it is acceptable to remove the interleaving of stdout / stderr, then this solution could help:

```
use std::io::{BufRead,BufReader};
use std::process::{Command,Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut child =
        Command::new("/tmp/output")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn().unwrap();

    if let Some(ref mut stdout) = child.stdout {
        for line in BufReader::new(stdout).lines() {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            println!("[stdout] {}", line);
        }
    }

    if let Some(ref mut stderr) = child.stderr {
        for line in BufReader::new(stderr).lines() {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            println!("[stderr] {}", line);
        }
    }

    let status = child.wait().unwrap();
    println!("Finished with status {:?}", status);
}
```

Comment: I guess Open AI answer is copied from yours.  :)

Comment: For interleaving , you may create two separate threads to handle each stream: stdout and stderr, and then print both to console.