# Merge child process stdout and stderr

Tags: rust

How do I merge child process stdout and stderr?

The following does not work since ownership cannot be shared between `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
let pipe = Stdio::piped();
let prog = Command::new("prog")
                        .stdout(pipe)
                        .stderr(pipe)
                        .spawn()
                        .expect("failed to execute prog");
```

In other words, what is the Rust equivalent of `2>&1` in the shell?

Comment: I was looking for something like `let pipe2 = Stdio::from_raw_fd(pipe.to_raw_fd())`, but I can't see an implementation of `AsRawFd` in the documentation, annoyingly.

Comment: I'm not sure if `Stdio::piped()` is what you need, but why not just use `.stdout(Stdio::piped()).stderr(Stdio::piped())`? [RustByExample](http://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/process/pipe.html) does this.

Comment: @Manishearth That sounds like it will redirect stdin and stdout to two *separate* pipes. The OP might want to redirect them to the same pipe without losing ordering information between their contents. The equivalent Bourne shell construct is, for instance, `output=$(command 2>&1)`.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/871

Answer (score 15):

My [`duct`](https://github.com/oconnor663/duct.rs) crate supports this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate duct;

fn main() {
    cmd!("echo", "hi").stderr_to_stdout().run();
}
```

The "right way" to do something like this, which `duct` is doing for you under the covers, is to create a double-ended OS pipe and pass the write end of it to both stdout and stderr. The standard library's `Command` class supports this sort of thing in general because `Stdio` implements `FromRawFd`, but unfortunately the standard library doesn't expose a way to create pipes. I've written another crate called [`os_pipe`](https://github.com/oconnor663/os_pipe.rs) to do this inside of `duct`, and if you want you can use it directly.

*This has been tested on Linux, Windows, and macOS.*

Comment: @jack-oconnor great library!  This is one of those "seems easy" problems that actually quite hard to get right.  Your library should be part of `std` IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing in the standard library that does this for you. Doesn't mean you can't write it yourself. This also means you get to decide how frequently each file descriptor is read and how to combine the data from each of the file descriptors. Here, I attempt to read in chunks using the default `BufReader` size and prefer to put stdout data first when both descriptors have data.

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut child =
        Command::new("/tmp/output")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Couldn't run program");

    let mut output = Vec::new();

    // Should be moved to a function that accepts something implementing `Write`
    {
        let stdout = child.stdout.as_mut().expect("Wasn't stdout");
        let stderr = child.stderr.as_mut().expect("Wasn't stderr");

        let mut stdout = BufReader::new(stdout);
        let mut stderr = BufReader::new(stderr);

        loop {
            let (stdout_bytes, stderr_bytes) = match (stdout.fill_buf(), stderr.fill_buf()) {
                (Ok(stdout), Ok(stderr)) => {
                    output.write_all(stdout).expect("Couldn't write");
                    output.write_all(stderr).expect("Couldn't write");

                    (stdout.len(), stderr.len())
                }
                other => panic!("Some better error handling here... {:?}", other)
            };

            if stdout_bytes == 0 && stderr_bytes == 0 {
                // Seems less-than-ideal; should be some way of
                // telling if the child has actually exited vs just
                // not outputting anything.
                break;
            }

            stdout.consume(stdout_bytes);
            stderr.consume(stderr_bytes);
        }
    }

    let status = child.wait().expect("Waiting for child failed");
    println!("Finished with status {:?}", status);
    println!("Combined output: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&output))
}
```

The biggest gap is telling when the process has exited. I'm surprised by the lack of a relevant method on `Child`.

See also [How do I prefix Command stdout with [stdout] and [sterr]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29458970/155423)

---

In this solution, there isn't any intrinsic ordering between the file descriptors. As an analogy, imagine two buckets of water. If you empty a bucket and later see that it's been filled up again, you know the second bucket came after the first. However, if you empty two buckets and come back later and both are filled up, you can't tell which bucket was filled first.

The "quality" of interleaving is a matter of how frequently you read from each file descriptor and which file descriptor is read first. If you read a single byte from each in a very tight loop, you might get completely garbled results but these would be the most "accurate" with regard to ordering. Likewise, if a program prints "A" to stderr then "B" to stdout but the shell reads from stdout before stderr, then the result would be "BA", which looks backwards.

Comment: The solution provided in the answer is not equivalent to the `2>&1` style redirection because it loses ordering information (as correctly described in the answer). In unstable Rust there is a `before_exec` method which could be used to perform `unsafe { libc::dup2(1, 2) }` - except that would only work on Unix-like platforms.

Comment: Yeah the ordering may not be totally deterministic in the general case but consider the case when all output is generated on a single thread in the child process. In this case there is going to be strict ordering between all "printfs" in the program. This ordering information is lost when the printfs print to different pipes but if they print to the same pipe then you will always be able to know the order in which the messages were printed.

Comment: This solution works only if both STDOUT and STDERR receive input since `stdout.fill_buf()` and `stderr.fill_buf()` block the thread they are on until they receive input or the stream they observe closes. The solution is to listen to both streams in separate threads. To do that, call `child.stdout.take()` instead of `child.stdout.as_mut()` to get ownership of the output stream listeners.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [io-mux crate](https://github.com/joshtriplett/io-mux/) to provide a multi-ended pipe-like construct; the primary use case is to capture stdout and stderr from a process, properly interleaved, and distinguish which data came from which one. See [highlight-stderr](https://github.com/joshtriplett/highlight-stderr) for an example of how to use it.

(io-mux primarily works on Linux; it can work on other UNIX platforms as well, but there it has some limitations that arise from the behavior of UNIX sockets on those platforms.)

If you don't care about distinguishing which data came from stdout and which data came from stderr, you can use a normal pipe. On UNIX, use [`libc::pipe`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.71/libc/fn.pipe.html) to create a pipe, [`Stdio::from_raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#implementations) twice to create stdout and stderr, spawn the process, and then read from the other end of the pipe. On Windows, you can do something similar, using handles rather than file descriptors.

If you don't need to distinguish which data came from stdout and which data came from stderr, and you don't want to deal with the platform-specific details of setting up a pipe, try something like [subprocess](https://crates.io/crates/subprocess), which specifically mentions support for combining stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking about [`std::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) but just in case it helps anyone using the [subprocess](https://crates.io/crates/subprocess) crate you can do this with [`Redirection::Merge`](https://docs.rs/subprocess/0.2.6/subprocess/enum.Redirection.html#variant.Merge):

```
.stderr(Redirection::Merge)
```